# How to create and assign static IP range in Terraform

Tags: terraform, vsphere, terraform-provider-vsphere

I'm learning Terraform and I do have a question: How to create and assign static IP range in Terraform + vSphere? Today I have a range of static IPs that can be used/assigned to the VMs (e.g. 192.168.25.10/24 - 192.168.25.50/24). I'd like to assign those IPs when configuring environment via Terraform based on number of VMs to be created. If I create 5 VMs, the IP to be used will be 192.168.25.10 - 14. Is that possible? I can do something like that today, but it is a manual and painful process (see below), especially if I decide to spin 30+ VMs. Hopefully there is a better way to do this.

```
#How it is configured today
#terraform.tfvars
vm_ips = {
  "0" = "192.168.25.10"
  "1" = "192.168.25.11"
  "2" = "192.168.25.12"
  "3" = "192.168.25.13"
  "4" = "192.168.25.14"
}

#variables.tf
variable "vm_ips" {
  type        = map(any)
  description = "List of IPs used for the Vms"
}

#main.tf
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vms" {
  count            = length(var.vm_ips)
  name             = "${var.guest_name_prefix}-vm0${count.index + 1}"
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.target_cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id     = data.vsphere_datastore.target_datastore.id
  folder           = var.deploy_vsphere_folder
...
     network_interface {
        ipv4_address = lookup(var.vm_ips, count.index)
        ipv4_netmask = var.guest_ipv4_netmask
```

Comment: Are you worried about the local variable or about the code to assign the IPs?

Comment: Why not `10 + count` and then implicitly cast to string during the interpolation?

Comment: @ Marki E - Just looking for an easy way to assign a block of static IPs to the VMs.

@ Matt Schuchard - Sorry, I did not get the idea. Any chance you could expand/exemplify on that, please?

Comment: Ok, but what is wrong with the current way of doing it? Also, current way of doing it will not work as the `vm_ips` is a map and you are trying to use `count`. You might consider using `for_each` instead.

Comment: Code works fine today however it is hard to scale-out. It is easy when I need to create a small environment, with 5 VMs, for example. But if I want to do it with 50 VMs, I will need to add all the 50 IPs to Terraform tf file (which kind defeats the purpose of automating/coding my infrastructure deployment). Looking for a better way to automate things where you just need to indicate number of VMs to be created then it will allocate the IP addresses from a IP pool. Makes sense?

Comment: Just to complement my answer, code is "stiff" and not very reusable atm. Don't want to hard code things, want code to be more dynamic/agile so it would be easier for other people to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a network range + element function : https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/element

Something like:

```
#terraform.tfvars
range_ips = "192.168.25.9/29"

#variables.tf
variable "range_ips" {
  description    = "Ip range from 192.168.25.9 - 14"
  type           = string
  default        = ""
}

#main.tf
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vms" {
  count            = length(var.range_ips)
  name             = "${var.guest_name_prefix}-vm0${count.index + 1}"
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.target_cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id     = data.vsphere_datastore.target_datastore.id
  folder           = var.deploy_vsphere_folder
...
     network_interface {
        ipv4_address = element(var.range_ips, count.index)
        ipv4_netmask = var.guest_ipv4_netmask
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you do `lengths(var.range_ips)` in terraform console, what would be the result?

Comment: It returns 15.

> length(var.range_ips)
15

Comment: Getting error below after applying @mrexojo:

│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on main.tf line 197, in resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vms":
│  197:         ipv4_address = element(var.range_ips, count.index)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is a number, known only after apply
│     │ var.range_ips is a string, known only after apply
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.

Comment: @mrexojo is that the real number of IPs in that CIDR? Since that is a string, it will return a value, however that is not a list so it can't be used with the rest of the code you provided.